# Imageview with cardview not getting rounded corner

Tags: java, android, xml

Hello i am making an app where i'm trying to make a cardview with imageview with rounded corner however when i run the app the rounded corners are not showing i dont know what exactly the problem is.
I tried using a custom imageview as well but when i sue that custom imageview imageis getting corner radius but black corners are showing on card and tried checking it on every api level like from android 5-8.
Please check my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/primary_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="35dp"
    app:contentPadding="0dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"

    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background_image_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/club1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/background_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ellipse" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
                        android:id="@+id/first_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="John Doe"
                        android:textColor="@color/White"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                       />

                    <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
                        android:id="@+id/second_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="checked in to"
                        android:textColor="@color/White"
                        android:textSize="10sp" />

                    <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
                        android:id="@+id/third_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="W south"
                        android:textColor="@color/White"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
                        android:id="@+id/fourth_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
                        android:text="beach mumbai"
                        android:textColor="@color/White"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                    <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
                        android:id="@+id/fifth_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/second_text"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fourth_text"
                        android:text="30 mins ago."
                        android:textColor="@color/White"
                        android:textSize="10sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="85dp">

            <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
                android:id="@+id/sixth_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="reply to abc............"
                android:textColor="@color/White" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/favourite_image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_black_24dp" />

                <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
                    android:id="@+id/seventh_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:text="40 likes"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

My code for custom imageview

```
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {
    private Path mMaskPath;
    private Paint mMaskPaint    = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    private int mCornerRadius   = 10;

    public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        init(context);
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);

        init(context);
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        ViewCompat.setLayerType(this, ViewCompat.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        mMaskPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        //mMaskPaint.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));

        mCornerRadius = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.image_border_curvature);
    }

    /**
     * Set the corner radius to use for the RoundedRectangle.
     */
    public void setCornerRadius(int cornerRadius) {
        mCornerRadius = cornerRadius;
        generateMaskPath(getWidth(), getHeight());
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldW, oldH);

        if (w != oldW || h != oldH) {
            generateMaskPath(w, h);
        }
    }

    private void generateMaskPath(int w, int h) {
        mMaskPath = new Path();
        mMaskPath.addRoundRect(new RectF(0,0,w,h), mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, Path.Direction.CW);
        mMaskPath.setFillType(Path.FillType.INVERSE_WINDING);
    }

    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if(canvas.isOpaque()) { // If canvas is opaque, make it transparent
            canvas.saveLayerAlpha(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), 255, Canvas.HAS_ALPHA_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG);
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if(mMaskPath != null) {
            canvas.drawPath(mMaskPath, mMaskPaint);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Include your current result and expected result, if possible.

Comment: I check your **xml** and I tried to run that.Its working properly.@Smith can you please post your current and expected result?

Answer (score -1):

See this -

[image]

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/reviewLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="35dp"
            app:contentPadding="0dp"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgProfile"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/profile" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi dhanshree i dont want to use circle imageview it is that my imageview inside cardview is not taking cornerradius

Comment: He asked about cardview radius effect over the image. The image he is using inside the cardview.